# Ahead in a coin flipping game

Tags: probability

In his book, "*A mathematician plays the stock market*", John Allen Paulos comments that if Henry and Tommy play a game consisting in flipping each one a coin 1000 times and counting a 1 if it's a head and 0 if it's a tail, then "it's considerably more probable that Henry (or Tommy) has been ahead more than, say, 96 percent of the time than that either one has been ahead between 48 percent and 52 percent of the time".

Thinking otherwise is the gambler's fallacy, as Paulo's comments. I *see* this result, and I think you can generate several experiments of 1000 times flipping coins and convince yourself (a kind of bootstrapping). But can it be proved analytically? I can't honestly see how. Thx.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof of this unintuitive stochastic behavior is in the so called arc-sine laws, and these require some effort to study and understand.

An intro presentation is here:
http://www.finanzaonline.com/forum/attachments/econometria-e-modelli-di-trading-operativo/1830328d1385649832-quiz-di-probabilita-molto-tecnico-difficile-arcsin-law.pdf

Comment: Actually, not *too* difficult, but very helpful.  Thanks.  (+1)